# Webpack rendering: "window is not defined"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, soundmanager2, mern

I use MERN – https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter (react, redux, webpack, nodejs, express)
And component react-sound – https://github.com/leoasis/react-sound

When I include component

```
import Sound from 'react-sound';
```

and try start the server, I have `"window is not defined"` error from webpack server rendering.

But if I comment this line and start the server, all will be fine. After that I can uncomment this line and component will be work, because when the server is running, changes don't triggered server rendering (only front rendering).

If I try

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    const Sound = require('react-sound');
}
```

And in render

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Sound playStatus={Sound.status.STOPPED} url="" />
        </div>
    );
}
```

I have `ReferenceError: Sound is not defined` error on front rendering (after webpack).

**UPDATE:**

If I try (`var`, not `const`)

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    var Sound = require('react-sound');
}
```

I have `TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined` error on front rendering.

Comment: defining const Sound inside the if block limits the scope to inside that block. bring var Sound =null; outside the if and then set the value in the if.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you can't use react-sound outside of a browser environment.

The solution can be as follows:

```
let SoundEl;
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  import Sound from 'react-sound';
  SoundEl = <Sound playStatus={Sound.status.STOPPED} url="" />
} else {
  SoundEl = <div></div>
}
```

...

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {SoundEl}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of ...

Comment: try const Sound = require('react-sound').default or import Sound from 'react-sound' (see answer updated)

Comment: Oops sorry, the problem was in <div></div>, it works ok that way if then it's rendered like {SoundEl}, but as it's not you have to make it a stateless component (see answer updated) https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components

Comment: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined. Because (I don't know why) it only works with import Sound from 'react-sound'; require don't want to work